# Bool type return rule

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, orm, dapper

I use dapper ORM.So i use two rules `Query<T>` & `QuerySingle<T>`. Query return the list & QuerySingle return the single object.

So,I want to get a bool type. (Actually I wanted to get a bool is true or false record).

My `Query<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string SqlString) where T : class
{
    return this.conn.Query<T>(SqlString);
}
```

So how can I write bool type return?

Comment: what does your sql query actually return?

Comment: If you want to use `bool` as the generic type then don't use the `class` constraint.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> So, I want to get a bool type. (Actually I wanted to get a bool is true
>   or false record)

You can write a method like this:

```
public bool GetBooleanValue(string sql)
{
    return the_connection.Query<bool>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The beauty about the `FirstOrDefault` is that when your query returns an empty row, Dapper will give you `false`. That suggested code will work as long as your query returns a value that can be translated into a boolean by your data provider. In case of SQL Server you would get:

- TRUE for `GetBooleanValue("select 1");`
- FALSE for `GetBooleanValue("select 0");`

**where** `1` and `0` are values from a table column of boolean type.

You can even use the code if you want to test if something exists or a group of values exists something like `GetBooleanValue("select COUNT(*) from the_table where the_column='some_filter'")`.

Comment: What if Count returns more than 1?

Comment: Any non-zero translates into "true"